# CoreBluetooth peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, characteristic) is not notifying

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I have two programs, one for Mac and one for iOS. When I connect to the iOS device from the Mac, it finds the services I want, and the characteristics I want. After finding the characteristic, I use `peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, forCharacteristic: characteristic)`, but the `peripheralManager:central:didSubscribeToCharacteristic:` method isn't being called on the iOS side. When I check if `characteristic.isNotifying` it is false. From what I understand when I set the notify value to true, it should be notifying, and whenever i change the value is updates. Why is it not updating? Thanks in advance.

Here is the code that sets up the characteristic in question -

```
self.characteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: UUID_CHARACTERISTIC, properties: CBCharacteristicProperties.Read, value: self.dataToSend, permissions: CBAttributePermissions.Readable) 
theService = CBMutableService(type: UUID_SERVICE, primary: true)
theService.characteristics = [characteristic]
self.peripheralManager.addService(theService)
```

Comment: Have you set the properties on the characteristic to allow notifications - show the code that sets up the service on the OS X side

Comment: for char in service.characteristics {
            var aCharacteristic: CBCharacteristic = char as CBCharacteristic;
            println("\t\tFound characteristic \(aCharacteristic)")
            peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, forCharacteristic: aCharacteristic)
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your characteristic to support `notify` operations then you need to set this on its properties -

```
self.characteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: UUID_CHARACTERISTIC, properties: CBCharacteristicProperties.Read|CBCharacteristicProperties.Notifiy, value: self.dataToSend, permissions: CBAttributePermissions.Readable);
```

An attempt to set notification on a characteristic that doesn't state support for notification is ignored by Core Bluetooth.

Also, be aware that by setting a value when the characteristic is created, you will not be able to change the value of this characteristic in the future - therefore notification is somewhat pointless. If you want to be able to change the value you must specify `nil` for `value` when you create the characteristic.

From the `CBMutableCharacteristic` documentation -

> **Discussion**
>
> If you specify a value for the characteristic, the value is
>   cached and its properties and permissions are set to
>   CBCharacteristicPropertyRead and CBAttributePermissionsReadable,
>   respectively. Therefore, if you need the value of a characteristic to
>   be writeable, or if you expect the value to change during the lifetime
>   of the published service to which the characteristic belongs, you must
>   specify the value to be nil. So doing ensures that the value is
>   treated dynamically and requested by the peripheral manager whenever
>   the peripheral manager receives a read or write request from a
>   central. When the peripheral manager receives a read or write request
>   from a central, it calls the peripheralManager:didReceiveReadRequest:
>   or the peripheralManager:didReceiveWriteRequests: methods of its
>   delegate object, respectively.